# How to get context from fragment under this circumstance?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

i've already implemented this thing in my application using activity,
refer image link below
 "https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRO4X.jpg"

in the first part you can see the `context=PerformanceActivity@4015`

but in the 2nd part it is null

the code i've used is

**IN ACTIVITY:**

```
viewHolder.nextReview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int d=v.getId();
                ((PerformanceActivity)context).performReview(v.getId());
            }
        });
```

**IN FRAGMENT:**

> NOTE: PerformanceFragment pf;

```
viewHolder.nextReview.setId(resData.get(position).getTestID());
        viewHolder.nextReview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int d=v.getId();
                ((PerformanceFragment)pf).performReview_frag(v.getId());
            }
        });
```

Both the methods are methods present in the adapter of a listview. In Activity It just works fine, but not in fragment.

Links to both adapters:

> https://pastee.org/28chw - Fragment's Adapter https://pastee.org/nw8rr
>   - Fragment
>
> https://pastee.org/wxepy -Activity's Adapter

Comment: pass context through constructor ....

Comment: @ursgtm context is already passed through constructor as `PerformanceFragmentAdapter adapter = new PerformanceFragmentAdapter(context,rsuData,device);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last this worked for me -

```
PerformanceFragmentAdapter adapter = new PerformanceFragmentAdapter(context,rsuData,device,this);
```

and adding this to the adapter as

```
private PerformanceFragment pf;
    public PerformanceFragmentAdapter(Context conte, ArrayList<ResultData> rData,
                              int device, PerformanceFragment pp) {
        super();
        context = conte;
        resData = rData;
        size = device;
        pf=pp;
    }
```

guess @ursgtm is right. still confusing between `Context c=getActivity();` and `this` keyword

Answer (score 0):

In second part use `getActivity()` method if your fragment `PerformanceFragment` is associated with your activity `PerformanceActivity`

```
viewHolder.nextReview.setId(resData.get(position).getTestID());
    viewHolder.nextReview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int d=v.getId();
            /* (getActivity()). no need to use content if 
            performReview_frag() is present in PerformanceFragment fragment*/
            // this will call performReview_frag() method
            performReview_frag(v.getId());
        }
    });
```

Else,

You can use `getBaseContext()` method to get correct context

Comment: Actually i dont need it with the activity(With activity it is working fine). The solution i need is with fragment. getActivity() method throws error. performReview_frag() is present in the PerformanceFragment. The id returning from view is also correct but i don't know how to get context of that fragment inside this adapter.

Comment: @Arun : I have editted code snippet.. I request you to check and update me if it is correct solution for you

Answer (score 0):

In `PerformanceFragmentAdapter` class :

```
 PerformanceFragment pf;
```

You are just creating a object with no instance and you are using that object as context,and you are not assigning anything to `pf` .

Instead of remove `pf`, and pass the context which you got from constructor:

```
viewHolder.nextReview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int d=v.getId();
           //Replace ((PerformanceFragment)pf) with context 
                context.performReview_frag(v.getId()); //you obtained context from contractor. 
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps you !